# Downloading large file from AWS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a AWS Windows Instance with SQL Server running on it.

I took a database backup and the resultant file is of size 175 GB.

What is the fastest and most efficient way of downloading this file from AWS to my local machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Network bandwidth** varies with the size of Amazon EC2 instances. Put simply, larger instances have larger bandwidth.

Your own Internet bandwidth will also be a limiting factor.

To fully utilize the available bandwidth, you could use the [Tsunami UDP protocol](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/moving-big-data-into-the-cloud-with-tsunami-udp/). This is similar in concept to Bittorrent, in that it has large windows and does not wait for error correction.

Amazon S3 actually [supports the Bittorrent protocol](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3Torrent.html), so you could copy the file to S3, then use Bittorrent to download it. This would be great at recovering from transmission errors. However, it means you are sending the file twice through constrained resources (the EC2 instance to S3, then S3 to your computer), which would be less efficient.